# Realm kotlin json to model

Tags: android, mongodb, kotlin, realm

I have this json data and I want to convert it to Realm model:

```
{
"_id": "63dceb34a8c4bbeee1c807f9",
"weeks": [2, 3, 2, 3],
}
```

and this is my kotlin model:

```
open class ProgramDoc() : RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    var _id: String = "",
    var weeks: RealmList<Int> = realmListOf<Int>()

}
```

But I got this error:

```
ProgramDoc.sessionPerWeek has type io.realm.kotlin.types.RealmList, got java.util.ArrayList
```

Any help please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that in your JSON data contains an `ArrayList` but your `Realm` model is expecting a `RealmList`.

What you can do is convert the `ArrayList` to a `RealmList` before mapping it to your `Realm` model.

```
open class ProgramDoc : RealmObject() {
    @PrimaryKey
    var _id: String = ""
    var weeks: RealmList<Int> = RealmList()
}
```

Example of how to get `ProgramDoc` model from a `json` :

```
val jsonObject = JSONObject(YOUR_JSON_HERE)

val programDoc = ProgramDoc(
    _id = jsonObject.getString("_id"),
    weeks = RealmList(jsonObject.getJSONArray("weeks").toList().map { it as Int })
)
```

Comment: this should work